# How to use integration tests with unlocked packages?

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, unlocked-package

How integration tests paradigm matches with the multiple unlocked packages in the org? Should one package has it's own unit tests and only UNIT tests (no integration tests)? Is it a good idea to separate all integration tests and run them only in the orgs where all unlocked packages installed (not only one or two for the development needs)?